# QtApp-debug.apk not being built

Tags: android, windows, qt, debugging, ant

I am using Qt 5.4
I am getting

`-- File: C:/Users/Username/Desktop/Desktop/Code/Test/Projects/accelbubble/Debug/android-build//bin/QtApp-debug.apk`

in the console.

I think the problem is with the `...build//bin/...` instead of `...build/bin/...`

(double slash instead of single slash)

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: The problem is probably Desktop/Desktop/

Comment: How so? It is just another folder. In any case, I tried simply D: drive.
Still the same error...
Oh, and BTW, Desktop/Desktop is a valid folder. I have a folder Desktop on my actual Desktop (I know)

Comment: Just thought it could be a typo. Can you paste the actual error ? Or a more complete qtcreator output